# Why might ServiceConfiguration.GetCurrent return a null object reference after log out / log in?

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif, acs

I have a Windows Azure application, consisting of an MVC4 web role and a suite of service roles, both worker and web, all built using the June 2012 SDK. My MVC role is secured using WIF/ACS and passive redirect. My services are accessible only via internal endpoints and are not secured.

Authentication and authorization with WIF/ACS generally works fine, but sometimes if I sign out of one account and then quickly, from my browser history, go back to the Index page, expecting to be asked to log in again, I am instead presented with the following YSOD:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

 Source Error:

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

 Stack Trace:

 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ServiceConfiguration.GetCurrent() +123
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromHttpContext(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean clientCertificateAuthenticationEnabled) +29
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +91
    System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +79
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +269
```

I thought at first this might be a case of cookies not getting cleared out, but surprisingly it seems the entire MVC site has crashed, and this error is visible from any browser, and from other machines. The only fix I've found is to restart the role.

Since passive redirection is set up in web.config, and is applied automatically using the STS wizard, I suspect I'm doing something wrong when I log the user out. My logout code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult CompleteLogOut(Boolean total, String provider = "")
    {
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        fam.SignOut(true);
        if (total)
        {
            provider = @"logout:" + provider;
            return Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[provider]);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

... where if 'total' is true the user is redirected to the logout page for their identity provider, either https://accounts.google.com/Logout or https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0 in my test setup.

I've only noticed the error happening when my logout is 'total', but since it is in any case an intermittent error, I can't be sure this is always true.

Googling the error throws up [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/e30c655f-d41a-4045-b311-4020d4fd97ff), which doesn't seem immediately relevant, but leads me to wonder if I need to be disposing the WSFederationAuthenticationModule after I log out?

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or does anybody have an idea what the issue might be?

**UPDATE**:

"it seems the entire MVC site has crashed, and this error is visible from any browser" - I don't think this is right, in fact. Just two separate users experiencing the same error, coincidentally at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well, I found the answer to this, but I don't fully understand it.

In order to track users, I set a session variable in Global.asax as soon as someone begins a new session:

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("MySession", Session.SessionID);
    }
```

This gets MVC to create a session, so I can track user activity with the SessionID (otherwise MVC will create a new session for each request).

If I dispose of my session explicitly when logging out, then the above error goes away:

```
    public ActionResult CompleteLogOut(Boolean total, String provider = "")
    {
        var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        try
        {
            fam.SignOut(true);
        }
        catch {}
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fam.Dispose();
                fam = null;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        if (total)
        {
            provider = @"logout:" + provider;
            return Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[provider]);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggedOutRedirect"]);
        }
    }
}
```

And if the user is not logging all the way out of their identity provider, I also need to redirect to the absolute URI of my home page, not just redirect to the action method.

Not sure why the session has to be cleared and abandoned for WIF to work again. Does WIF use the session internally? Perhaps someone can shed more light, but in any case the logout routine above works and hopefully may save somebody else from wrestling with the same bug in future.